# Can't generate the correct value on the if and else if statements that belongs to the specific category

Tags: c++

The code expects to get only a single value that belongs to the category that I have specified.

If the input is 2, the code shows a "First Class Honors", which is wrong. I expect to get a 'Pass'.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int GPA;
    
    cout << "What is your GPA?: ";
    cin >> GPA;
    
    if (3.7 <= GPA <= 4)
    {
        cout << "First Class Honors\n";
    }
    
    else if (3.4 <= GPA < 3.7)
    {
        cout << "Second Up Class Honors\n";
    }
    
    else if (3 <= GPA < 3.4)
    {
        cout << "Second Low Class Honors\n";
    }

    else if (2.7 <= GPA < 3)
    {
        cout << "Third Class Honors\n";
    }

    else if (GPA < 2.7)
    {
        cout << "Pass\n";
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `3.7 <= GPA <= 4` does not do what you think it does. In which C++ textbook did you see something like this?

Comment: C++ doesn't understand you combined comparisons; *A <= B < C* should be written as *(A<=B)&&(B<C)*.

Comment: `(3.7 <= GPA <= 4)` -- C++ syntax is not the same as schoolbook math syntax.

Comment: Side note, if you are expecting decimal precision GPA then you should use `double GPA` (or `float`) instead of `int`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain your comparisons like

```
if (3.7 <= GPA <= 4)
```

instead that would be written

```
if (3.7 <= GPA && GPA <= 4)
```

and similar for the other branches

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this code?

The correct syntax would be as shown below:

```
    if ((GPA >= 3.7) && (GPA <= 4))
    {
        cout << "First Class Honors\n";
    }
    
    else if ((GPA >= 3.4) && (GPA < 3.7))
    {
        cout << "Second Up Class Honors\n";
    }
    
    else if ((GPA >= 3) && (GPA < 3.4))
    {
        cout << "Second Low Class Honors\n";
    }

    else if ((GPA >= 2.7) && (GPA < 3))
    {
        cout << "Third Class Honors\n";
    }

    else if (GPA < 2.7)//can also use else here instead of else if
    {
        cout << "Pass\n";
    }
```

Also note that you can consider `else` instead of using `else if` for the last check. Also note the brackets `()` around individual checks are **optional** in this case.That is, the program will behave the same if you write `if ((GPA >= 3.7) && (GPA <= 4))` as:

```
if (GPA >= 3.7 && GPA <= 4)
```

Similarly for other cases.